# How to enable sound in qemu?

Tags: sound, qemu

I am developing a plosia (persistent libre operating system for industrial applications) that is self contained on a high speed usb micro thumb drive. I wish to use QEMU for screen recording the whole setup and usage phases of the system. For the purpose of this question both the host and the guest are the same system in layout, they are both based on Ubuntu-Mate. For testing and demonstration purposes
I want to screen record the setup process and other tasks to show it off. This qemu command allows me to boot to my usb drive and gives me great speed
and video performance:

BOOT_USB="/dev/sdf"; sudo qemu-system-x86_64 -machine accel=kvm:tcg -m 4096 -bios /usr/share/ovmf/OVMF.fd -smp 16 -vga virtio -display gtk,gl=on -hda $BOOT_USB

Video is fast and smooth, processing speed is acceptable. Only one thing missing that I need and that is sound. I wish to both hear the vm and record it with obs in the rest
of the screen recording utility.

Googling this:

qemu-system-x86_64 enable sound

leads me to the first link which is
https://techpiezo.com/linux/enable-audio-in-qemu-virtual-machine/

The instructions look simple. I tried this command

qemu-system-x86_64 -soundhw help

and one of the options is sb16 which a friend recommended as something which worked for him.

So I modified my command line like this per the instructions:

BOOT_USB="/dev/sdf"; sudo qemu-system-x86_64 -soundhw sb16 -machine accel=kvm:tcg -m 4096 -bios /usr/share/ovmf/OVMF.fd -smp 16 -vga virtio -display gtk,gl=on -hda $BOOT_USB

No special sound errors were thrown by this. However the sound panel still says dummy output and no sound comes out of the host speakers.

I seem to have a fundamental problem understanding how sound is routed through qemu and the host computer speakers. Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

I'm using Ubuntu-Mate 20.04. According to lspci my soundcard is this:

09:00.3 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) HD Audio Controller

Answer (score 3):

N0rbert's utility didn't do exactly what I wanted however by inspecting the sourcecode I was able to make my commandline work like this:

```
BOOT_USB="/dev/sdb"
sudo cp ~/.config/pulse/cookie /root/.config/pulse/cookie
sudo qemu-system-x86_64 -machine accel=kvm:tcg -m 4096 -bios /usr/share/ovmf/OVMF.fd -audiodev pa,id=pa,server=unix:${XDG_RUNTIME_DIR}/pulse/native,out.stream-name=foobar,in.stream-name=foobar -device intel-hda -device hda-duplex,audiodev=pa,mixer=off -rtc base=localtime,clock=host -smp 16 -vga virtio -display gtk,gl=on -drive file=$BOOT_USB,format=raw,index=0,media=disk
```

I don't think I can explain all the details on how this works but I'll leave my solution here for others. In the command at the beginning is a fix for pulse audio. Sometimes it works sometimes it doesn't but with the cp command it works fairly consistantly. A couple days after finding the solution I discovered another problem with my handling of the format of the disk. The new command is safer and there are no warnings or errors. The command will boot a uefi enabled USB drive with my copy of rEFInd. It applies accelerated graphics and audio. You can add a data drive to this commandline with this option

```
-drive file=/dev/sdc,format=raw,if=virtio
```

OBS captured footage looks stunningly clear and smooth from the vm. Even playing full hd 60fps youtube video.

Answer (score 2):

Using Pipewire, the `-audiodev pa` did not work even with the `pipewire-pulse` plugin. To work around this, libvirt some times (usually?) adds the following instead:

```
-device ich9-intel-hda,id=sound0,bus=pcie.0,addr=0x1b -device hda-duplex,id=sound0-codec0,bus=sound0.0,cad=0 \
    -global ICH9-LPC.disable_s3=1 -global ICH9-LPC.disable_s4=1
```

Did the trick for me, hopefully it'll be useful to other people who is moving away from Pulseaudio and starts using Pipewire instead.

You can also run this entirely in user-space, so no need to copy magical cookies and things.

Answer (score 1):

To ease the QEMU setup process you can use [QuickEMU](https://github.com/wimpysworld/quickemu).

```
sudo apt-get install git
git clone https://github.com/wimpysworld/quickemu.git

sudo apt-get install snapd
snap install qemu-virgil --edge
snap connect qemu-virgil:audio-record
snap connect qemu-virgil:kvm
snap connect qemu-virgil:raw-usb
snap connect qemu-virgil:removable-media

cat << EOF > ~/vm.conf
boot="legacy"
guest_os="linux"
iso="/path/to/file.iso"
disk_img="/home/$USER/path/to/disk.qcow2"
disk=16G
EOF
```

And then run it

```
./quickemu --vm ~/vm.conf
```

The resulting VM will have sound, SMB, SSH, USB, good video performance and other features.

---

Note: under the hood QuickEMU sets `-audiodev` option with [corresponding parameters](https://github.com/wimpysworld/quickemu/blob/master/quickemu#L415).

Comment: This looks promising. How do I boot from a usb drive instead of a qcow imge?

Comment: I was too late, but it is great that you have solved the USB booting issue. I have added [feature request to QuickEMU](https://github.com/wimpysworld/quickemu/issues/52).